# html5 canvas memory leak

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am developing a camera based SPA. When I'm trying to resize the image it cause to a memory leak.

**without executing resize**

[image: memory snapshot at beginning]

**first executing resize**

[image].

**second executing resize**

[image]

The memory never go down until I do refresh.

It is strange the same app http://shitu.baidu.com does release the memory.
Here is the my resize function.

```
var useRightPen = function (img, pre_img_wid, pre_img_hei, aft_img_wid, aft_img_hei, callback) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.setAttribute("height", aft_img_hei);
    canvas.setAttribute("width", aft_img_wid);

    var orientation = 1;
    if (!!(/http/.test(img.src))) {
          //memory keeps the same before the drawimage
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, aft_img_wid, aft_img_hei);
         //memory goes up after the draimage
        callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'), aft_img_wid, aft_img_hei);
    }
    canvas = null;
}
```

Appreciate for everyone.

**---update--06-11--2015**

I make one fildde http://jsfiddle.net/onTheRoad/dc17guba/

The demo will reset the image src after every pick.Memory goes high on its way.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you check if it is browser-specific? How does memory consumption behave in Firefox or Internet Explorer?

Comment: Just because the amount of allocated memory has grown in the task manager it **does not** mean it's a memory leak.

Comment: `!!(/http/.test(img.src))` is ugly. Does not `.test()` always return a boolean? `canvas = null;` --- this is redundant and must be removed.

Comment: Use the profiler to be sure there is a memory leak.
Have you tried to clear the canvas before drawing again? `canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

Comment: My app always goes crash when take photo in ios or android browser .And the browser reload my app and give me a tip 'run out of memory'.I have checked the firefox desktop browser.The memory does the same action as chrome do.

Comment: Why do you think this is a memory leak? Running out of memory and a memory leak aren't necessarily the same thing

Comment: Memory goes up not because of the drawImage, but because of the getContext that allocates a buffer. What are you doing in the actual callback ? If you hold a reference to the jpeg image, memory use will only keep growing.

Comment: Important question, in which moment do you take the picture? I mean, is not the same take a picture on a click event that take multiple pictures while canvas video is "recording". Which is your event to call useRightPen?